# `Solving environment: failed` error when doing `conda env`

Tags: anaconda

I have python 3.7 and latest anaconda.

I am having Solving environment: failed issue with this error code.

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - jpeg==9c=h470a237_1
```

Could anyone teach me how to solve this problem?

```
(base) Koos-MBP:downloads jackykoo$ conda env create -f cvcourse_macos.yml 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - jpeg==9c=h470a237_1
  - twisted==17.5.0=py36_0

(base) Koos-MBP:downloads jackykoo$
```

Here is my conda info

```
(base) Koos-MBP:downloads jackykoo$ conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/jackykoo/opt/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/jackykoo/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/jackykoo/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /Users/jackykoo/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/jackykoo/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/jackykoo/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/jackykoo/opt/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/jackykoo/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Darwin/19.0.0 OSX/10.15
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```